# Is there a way to get the current imagebase of a 64-bit .exe file in python?

Tags: python, pointers, memory, exe, ctypes

I can get the prefered imagebase, but to calculate the memory address of a variable with a pointer, I need to get the current imagebase of the .exe file. Remember it´s 64-bit and calling the ReadWriteMemory.get_pointer() function with a 64-bit offset returns an overflow error because int is too large to convert.

Comment: That's an easy thing to fix.  Change `read` to use `read_buffer = ctypes.c_uint64()`.

Comment: What library are you referring to?  Please follow the [mcve] rules.

Comment: And sure, there is a way.  Refer to the PSAPI library for Windows.